# Probability problem with dice having blank spaces

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> An ordinary cube has four blank faces, one face marked $2$ and another marker $3$. Then the probability of obtaining $9$ in $5$ throws is

**Attempt 1**

Favourable events are $A(3,3,3,0,0), A(3,2,2,2,0)$

$P(2)=P(3)=\dfrac{1}{6}; P(0)=\dfrac{4}{6}$

$$
\text{Req. Prob.}=P(A)+P(B)={\frac{5!}{3!\cdot2!}}P(3)P(3)P(3)P(0)P(0)+{\frac{5!}{3!}}P(3)P(2)P(2)P(2)P(0)\\
=\frac{5!}{3!\cdot2!}\cdot\frac{1}{6^3}\cdot\left(\frac{4}{6}\right)^2+\frac{5!}{3!}\cdot\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^4\cdot\frac{4}{6}
$$

Why am I thinking this way ?

I think I am messing with the probability of obtaining the blank face $0$, is it $1/6$ or $4/6$ ?

Comment: Assuming that the die is fair, each face has an equal probability of being at the top, and there are four blanks out of six.

Comment: @amd so if we take independent sample even corresponding to blank face, each have the probability $1/6$. Whilst if we talking about probability of obtaining a blank space it is $4/6$, is it the difference ?

Comment: That’s right. Four out of six of the atomic events produce a $0$.

Comment: @amd sounds simple but was making me mad while solving it.